# TensorFlow train.string_input_producer reads CSV file multiple times

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I'm using the standard input pipeline for reading CSV files in TensorFlow. I have a single input file that I want to read in using mini-batches. My concern is that the file is being read multiple times even though I believe I have set the number of epochs properly. I think this may be due to the behavior of the train.string_input_producer() function.

```
with self.graph.as_default():
        epochs = np.floor(fileSize / batchSize) + 1
        self.fileNameQ = tf.train.string_input_producer(fileNameList, num_epochs = epochs)
        self.batchInput, self.label = self.inputPipeline(batchSize, dim)
```

Here, fileSize is determined by:

```
fileSize = sum(1 for line in open(file.name))
```

I've defined my input pipeline function as follows:

```
def readFromCsv(self, dim):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, csvLine = reader.read(self.fileNameQ)
    recordDefaults = [["\0"] for cl in range(dim + 3)]
    recordStr = tf.decode_csv(csvLine, record_defaults=recordDefaults)
    self.label = tf.stack(recordStr[0:3])
    self.features = tf.stack(recordStr[3:dim + 3])
    return (self.features, self.label)

def inputPipeline(self, batchSize, dim): 
    minAfterDequeue = 10000
    capacity = minAfterDequeue + 3 * batchSize
    example, label = self.readFromCsv(dim)
    exampleBatchStr, labelBatch = tf.train.batch([example, label], batch_size=batchSize, capacity=capacity)
    exampleBatch = tf.string_to_number(exampleBatchStr)
    return (tf.transpose(exampleBatch), tf.transpose(labelBatch))
```

Then I perform the training and print out a dot each time 1,000 records is processed.

```
def train(self, batchSize, dim):
    with self.sess:
        self.sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        # Start populating the filename queue.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        #Training iterations
        self.iterationInput = 0
        while self.iterationInput < self.iterations:
            #Train with each vector one by one
            self.iterationInput += 1
            print("iteration " + str(self.iterationInput) + " for window size " + str(dim))
            try:
                loopCount = 0
                while not coord.should_stop():
                #Fill in input data.
                    self.sess.run([self.batchInput, self.label])
                    self.sess.run(self.trainingOp)
                    #For every 1,000 samples, print a dot.
                    if loopCount % 1000 == 0:
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                        sys.stdout.write('.')
                    loopCount += 1
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print("Done training -- epoch limit reached")
                coord.request_stop()

        # When done, join the threads
        coord.join(threads)
```

The number of dots printed out while running the program is significantly more than the number of records (/ 1000) in the file. I know that train.string_input_producer() initializes four threads. I'm concerned that each of the threads is reading the file once, causing the runtime to increase when there is not sufficient parallelization in the hardware. Since the runtime is already long, I don't want to increase it any more than is necessary. Is there any way I can prevent the file from being read four times?

Comment: The problem is with how the number of epochs is being set. You should just set it to how many times you want to read the file regardless of batch size.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks!